# List of multiple column condition in query (kind of batch)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-webflux

when trying to search with single record then this query works

```
@Query(value = "select * from table t where t.column1 = :column1  and t.column2 = :column2 and t.column3 = :column3")
Flux<Invoice> findByMultipleColumn(@Param("column1”) String column1, @Param("column2”) String column2, @Param("column3”) String column3);
```

But when I have list of criterias instead of a single row condition then I have to loop over the list of criterias & call the above query multiple times which is not feasible solution.

Sudo code

```
for (Criteria criteria : criteriaList) {
            repository.findByMultipleColumn(criteria.getColumn1(), criteria.getColumn2(), criteria.getColumn3());
        }
```

What I am trying to find a way to solve the above query for multiple **LIST** of all the 3 column criteria pair, something like below (**this is not working solution**)

```
@Query(value = "select * from table t where t.column1 = :column1  and t.column2 = :column2 and t.column3 = :column3")
Flux<Invoice> findByMultipleColumn(@Param List<Table> table);
```

Is there any way somehow we can try to achieve the above case?

Answer (score 0):

Would be doable if column1, 2 and 3 were Embedded, then you could do

```
@Query(select * from Entity where embeddedProperty in (:values))
Flux<Entity> findByEmbeddedPropertyIn(Collection<EmbeddedClas> values);
```

Which would generate the following native SQL clause

```
Where (column1, column2, column3) in ((x, y, z), ...)
```

If you don't want to pack these fields i to an embeddable class, you can also try to do a workaround

```
@Query(select * from Entity where Concat(column1, ';', column2, ';', column3) in (:parametersConcatrenatedInJava)
Flux<Entity> findBy3Columns(Collection<String> parametersConcatrenatedInJava);
```

It's ofcourse not bulletproof, all three columns could have ";" as their values, this might be problematic if their type is not string, etc.

Edit.:

Third option is to use specification api. Using the criteria builder you can concatenate multiple and / or queries. And pass that specification as an argument to the repository that extends JpaSpecificationExecutor (if you're fetching whole entities) or an entity manager if you're using projections. [Read more about specifications](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries)